# GNOME Network Displays - PackageKit service not found, codecs not detected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, codec, miracast

What's up StackExchange-land :)

I'm currently running into an issue with getting PackageKit to install or recognize codecs on my system when using GNOME Network Displays on Ubuntu 23.10.

When I try to connect to a sink (a Roku TV in this case), GND prompts me to install one of three AAC codecs in order to connect to the sink. For context, I've tried installing GND from source, from flathub, and from APT, and all have this same issue at that step:

When I click to install one of the codecs:

[(screenshot of the GND window)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJuV3.png)

```
** Message: 23:47:47.371: PackageKit: xid = 0
** Message: 23:47:47.371: PackageKit: desktop_id = org.gnome.NetworkDisplays
** Message: 23:47:47.371: PackageKit: Codec nice name: GStreamer element fdkaacenc
** Message: 23:47:47.371: PackageKit: structure: gstreamer1(element-fdkaacenc)()(64bit)
** Message: 23:47:47.376: PackageKit: Did not install codec: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PackageKit was not provided by any .service files
```

I have tried purging and re-installing GND and `packagekit`

Additionally, I already have `faac` installed on my system, and GND isn't detecting it.

If any of you have had this issue or have any idea how to fix this, I'd greatly appreciate it :)